# Attempt to create a structure object creating an Access Violation Writing Error In Location 0x3FE00000

Tags: c++, structure

I'm learning to use structures and making a text-based RPG, and I'm aware that items should be a class in my code, however, since I am using structures and I'm new to c++ and programming I do not understand what exactly has gone wrong with my code nor how to fix it, the error occurs where I try to create a structure object called player. (I would also like to apologize for my messy code, i'm messing around and will be cleaning it once I get what I have working.)

This is my first attempt, I haven't tried much because I'm unsure what exactly to try.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct item {
    double resistance, attack;
    string name;
};
item none, WoodenBoots, LeatherChestplate, WoodenShield, WoodenClub, WoodenSword;


struct mobs {
    int health, attack;
    double droprate, resistance;
    item drops[3];
};

item GetData(string object);


int main()
{
    none.attack = 0;
    none.resistance = 0;
    none.name = "none";
    WoodenBoots.resistance = .05;
    WoodenBoots.attack = 0;
    WoodenBoots.name = "Wooden Boots";
    LeatherChestplate.resistance = .2;
    LeatherChestplate.attack = 0;
    LeatherChestplate.name = "Leather Chestplate";
    WoodenShield.resistance = .1;
    WoodenShield.attack = 0;
    WoodenShield.name = "Wooden shield";
    WoodenClub.resistance = 0;
    WoodenClub.attack = 1.2;
    WoodenClub.name = "Wooden Club";
    WoodenSword.resistance = .05;
    WoodenSword.attack = 1.5;
    WoodenSword.name = "Wooden Sword";

    mobs goblin;
    goblin.attack = 1;
    goblin.health = 10;
    goblin.droprate = .5;
    goblin.resistance = .1;
    goblin.drops[1] = WoodenClub;
    goblin.drops[2] = WoodenShield;
    goblin.drops[3] = WoodenBoots;

    mobs Alpha_Goblin;
    Alpha_Goblin.attack = 2;
    Alpha_Goblin.health = 15;
    Alpha_Goblin.droprate = .5;
    Alpha_Goblin.resistance = .1;
    Alpha_Goblin.drops[1] = WoodenSword;
    Alpha_Goblin.drops[2] = WoodenShield;
    Alpha_Goblin.drops[3] = LeatherChestplate;

    struct pdata {
        item Playeritem[6];
        item PlayerWeapon;
    }player;

    player.PlayerWeapon = WoodenSword;
    cout << player.PlayerWeapon.name << endl;

    player.PlayerWeapon = GetData("weapon");
    player.Playeritem[0] = GetData("sheild");
    player.Playeritem[1] = GetData("head");
    player.Playeritem[2] = GetData("torso");
    player.Playeritem[3] = GetData("legs");
    player.Playeritem[4] = GetData("feet");
    player.Playeritem[5] = GetData("hands");
    string weapon = player.PlayerWeapon.name;
    cout << weapon << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

I expect it to create the structure and to move on to defining the item values inside the struct. i get the following error on the last line of the struct pdata: Exception thrown at 0x57115139 (vcruntime140d.dll) in Structure.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x3FE00000.

Comment: Good starting point to get familiar with your IDE's debugger and check the stack trace.

Comment: Arrays in C and C++ have indexes starting at zero, not one.

Comment: What @NeilButterworth's comment means is that the valid elements for your `drops` tables are `drops[0]`, `drops[1]` and `drops[2]`. Thought it seems you got it right for `player.PlayerItem`.

Comment: thank you, i missed that, i now get another writing error in another script called xutility

Comment: Use your debugger and tell us which line is the last line to execute before the exception is thrown.

Comment: What is `GetData`? Are you absolutely sure that the issue isn't there? Perhaps it fails to return something when you misspell the object name and can't find it, like in `"sheild"?`

Comment: Thank you all, I spent hours looking into what went wrong and how structures work, I feel kind of silly seeing that I just forgot about c++ indexing starting at 0, I think I can figure out the other errors, ill now try to figure out how to mark this post as resolved. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

In C++ arrays are indexed from zero to num_elements - 1

So if you declare

```
int myArray[3];
```

and then try to access:

```
myArray[3] = 5;
```

You are going to get undefined behavior that may manifest itself as an access violation depending on your compiler and debug settings.

In Visual Studio you can use the Exception Settings and check off access violation exceptions while running in debug, and have the execution halt before it is thrown.

Comment: *You are going to get an access violation.* -> *You will get undefined behaviour that MAY manifest in an access violation.*